# (Error: expected primary-expression before '<<' token)

Tags: c++

I am trying to run the following code :-

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string animals[2][3] =
    {
        {"Fox", "Hyena", "Lion"},
        {"Goat", "Rooster", "Buffalo"}
    };
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << animals[i][j]; " ";
                    << flush;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but I'm receiving an error:

```
Error: expected primary-expression before '<<' token)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have extra `;` here:

```
cout << animals[i][j]; " ";
                << flush;
```

Instead, it needs to be:

```
cout << animals[i][j] << " " << flush;
```